# How to reference csv column name in D3.js on mouseover of a plotted line?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hopefully, I phrased the question accurately. I'm building a plot with multiple lines on it. The data (csv) is structured so that each line corresponds to a column. I'd like to update text on the graph with the respective column's name.

My data looks like this.

```
Period,datetime,North,South,East,West
2000 Q1, 2000-03-31, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
2000 Q2, 2000-06-30, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
2000 Q3, 2000-09-30, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
...
```

Each line corresponds to a region (one of the four last columns from above). So I defined regionLabel like this:

```
var regionLabel = d3.select("svg").append("text")
                                  .attr("class", "big label")
                                  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                                  .attr("y", margin.top * 2)
                                  .attr("x", margin.left + 10)
                                  .text(" ");
```

... and I'm calling the action like this:

```
d3.selectAll("path")
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("stroke", "orange")
      .attr("opacity", "1");
    regionLabel.text(incomingData[0]????)
  });
```

Question: Above you'll see "incomingData[0]????". This is obviously not correct. What do I enter there so that the label displays the line's region or column name (e.g. North, South...)?

Edit:

I'm reading the csv file this way:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) { makeGraph(data); });
```

...And most of the code resides in this function:

```
function makeGraph(incomingData) {
for (x in incomingData[0]) {
    if (x != "Period" && x != "datetime" && x != "date") { ... }
    }
```

The .on events are within the above "...".

Comment: Where do you set `incomingData`?

Comment: @praszyk I edited my question to, hopefully, make the answer to your question clear. Thanks!

Comment: Still not sure. Can you create a plunker of your code so I can look into it?

Comment: @praszyk I just created this: http://plnkr.co/edit/rBuDfoCFT0BSYpEIJIL7?p=catalogue . Unfortunately, I'll have to look into how to add the csv file. :/